# Chrome "Find..." toolbar icon

Tags: google-chrome, toolbar

Is it possible to have an icon (toolbar button) for "Find..." in Chrome? Perhaps next to the Back/Forward/Reload/Home?

[image: find icon]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible within the browser itself but [Spot: Better Find in Page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/spot-better-find-in-page/bbpdiffmmobnnngmfigpgddgjpgjgbol) is a Chrome extension that allows you to search the contents of a page and also includes some other handy features. The icon will be on the right side of the toolbar along with the other extension, but I assume that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Unfortunately Spot does not find the things build-in Find does, eg. when i try to search for "ext" it does not find the word "extension". It only matches the whole word "extension". 
As we know "[If It Isn't Incremental, It's Excremental](https://blog.codinghorror.com/search-if-it-isnt-incremental-its-excremental/)"